# Does GAC conflict with the Registry for Assembly Loading?

Tags: c#, vb6, .net-assembly, gac, regasm

I have a DLL I generate from a C# project. I then register it via `regasm` so that the library can be used inside several legacy VB scripts.

Recently I created a new project (C# console app) that will reuse certain modular aspects of the original library, and per good programming practice it made sense to add the library to the GAC for reuse by this and any future projects.

I've found that it plays nice at first, but after the server is rebooted, the VB scripts crash and burn, claiming they are unable to create an object of one of the types defined in the library.

The fix involves removing the library from the GAC and re-registering the library via `regasm`.

- The libraries in the registry and GAC come from the same physical DLL file - same directory and everything.
- I've confirmed the existence of registry entries for the library every step of the way, which says `regasm` did its job.
- GAC entries only exist when the library is installed, and properly disappear when it is uninstalled. They only ever appear under `GAC_MSIL`, where, to my knowledge, they should be.

Any ideas why this is happening?

EDIT: I did not read the fine print, haha. On the `regasm` documentation I just saw this: "Creates a Codebase entry in the registry. The Codebase entry specifies the file path for an assembly that's not installed in the global assembly cache. **Don't specify this option if you will subsequently install the assembly that you're registering into the global assembly cache.** It is strongly recommended the assemblyFile argument that you specify with the /codebase option be a strong-named assembly." I was using that switch, so I will dig deeper. In the meantime any additional insights are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure it really is best practice to have globally visible dependencies. IMO this was always a terrible weakness of desktop COM which is why MSFT later invented side-by-side loading.  So I wouldn't automatically assume you should put things in the GAC either, unless you really need to.

Comment: In fact it says something similar here: "*You should share assemblies by installing them into the Global Assembly Cache **only when you need to**. As a general guideline, keep assembly dependencies private, and locate assemblies in the application directory unless sharing an assembly **is explicitly required**. In addition, it is not necessary to install assemblies into the Global Assembly Cache to make them accessible to COM interop or unmanaged code*."   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/gac

Comment: Regarding the COM registration getting broken, if you run a test by copying the DLLs somewhere else (not the GAC location) and registering them there, does the problem still happen?

Comment: Thanks for the info. Just to clarify, you're talking about using purely `regasm`, or do you want me to emulate the entire process I described from a different working directory?

Comment: Right, I did meant just regasm from a different folder and then see if a reboot breaks things.

Comment: It doesn't appear to work. When you use `regasm /codebase`, the assembly becomes tied to the location it is referenced from. Referencing it from a new location won't work - even if the DLL exists in the original location, it loses visibility once unregistered. Digging in the registry seemed to confirm this as there are entries with assembly names, versions, and locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess you didn't renew the GUIDs and/or distinguish the fully qualified type names of the new library and when you installed it with `regasm`, the old entries in the registry got overwritten. Registering the old library again has overwritten the new library's registry, but as you don't use it through COM that didn't affect it and now the scripts work again.

Comment: Thanks for the info. What does it take to do the two things you mentioned?